# OpenGL Projection, View and World matrices

Tags: c, opengl, matrix, directx-9

I have question about OpenGL projection, view and model matrices.
In DirectX 9 i can easily manipulate matrix content and then apply it by using `SetTransform` [function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb174463(v=vs.85).aspx).

I saw in MSDN OpenGL `glLoadMatrixf` [function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee872049(v=vs.85).aspx), but it only changes current matrix which I can change by `glMatrixMode` [function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373949(v=vs.85).aspx).

This function gets one argument with 3 options: `GL_MODELVIEW`, `GL_PROJECTION` and `GL_TEXTURE`. But that's the problem. How can I modify world matrix?

In DirectX 9 I can use `SetTransform` and one of [state types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb172619(v=vs.85).aspx): `D3DTS_WORLD` (macro), `D3DTS_VIEW` and `D3DTS_PROJECTION` and set matrices for them.

Comment: Are you limited to using old, archaic functions? Also I would recommend never reading anything about OpenGL from Microsoft, ever.

Comment: Indeed, with shaders in openGL you can set and apply your matrices directly, (you can even opt to not use matrices at all)

Comment: Yep, I'm limited to using OpenGL < 3 (2.1 max), so the glUniform is out.

Comment: `glUniform` and shaders are available in 2.1. OpenGL 3 is where it starts _requiring_ them.

Comment: Oh... I didn't know about it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `GL_MODELVIEW` matrix is exactly what its name is; a combination of the model and view matrices. Usually, you apply your view transformations first, then for each model, you push a matrix, apply model transforms, draw the model, then pop the matrix.

If you use shaders, though, (and you have to in OpenGL 3.1+ without the compatibility profile), then you can use uniforms to pass matrices to the shader however you want, including splitting the model and view matrices if you so desire.